# Wrapping 3rd party web application with my own javascript functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Is it possible to inject **locally** some functionality on a specific web application, hosted elsewhere?

See, I'm not trying to crack the site, inject code to trap other users, or something like this. I only want to add functionality to the application as seen from my browser. Akin to add some accessibility functions (like client CSS, to circumvent the externally provided styles with something more accessible).

The functionality is written in javascript (with jquery) and actually just locates a specific `<div>`, reads some values (couple of `<li>` actually), crunches these values and output a nice graph chart just underneath.

Currently I thought of (but have not advanced too far in either direction, because I have conceptual questions in all of them):

- specially crafted CSS to be installed locally as client CSS, which will inject javascript whenever that web application is loaded (**is it possible to inject javascript this way?**);
- local file (say, mychart.html) with skeleton html + javascript, with an `<iframe>` loading the external application (**is it possible to run javascript on the outer frame and access contents on the inner frame?**);
- local file with some nice html mimicing the original `<div>`, with javascript fetching the original application underneath (ajax), rendering the entire DOM to fetch the `<li>`s and discarding the rest (**is it possible to get the DOM with jquery's ajax?**);
- "bookmark" my javascript function to the toolbar, so I can click it while viewing the 3rd party website and have it somehow display a floating div (or another window) with my chart (**it it even possible? how to display things then?**).

Any other option? It can be specific to FireFox, Chrome or IE (well, it would be nice if I can port between them, but I can search for similar approaches).

Any advice to offer on above options, about problems I should face ahead, sooner or later?

NB: It is not strictly necessary to draw the entire external page; it is not even necessary to draw any part of it; just need to get the values and output the chart (I have this part already done in javascript).

Comment: I just found out that the my 4th alternative is called [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first alternative, you can either use "user javascript" (take a look at [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) for Chrome) or develop a browser extension (and use, for example [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)).

Comment: do you know about any equivalent for Internet Explorer?

Comment: I have no idea for the recent versions of IE. There were IE7Pro and Trixie which worked up to IE8.